# undefined reference error while building app;

Tags: c++, blackberry-10, momentics

I'm getting this error while building a BlackBerry project:

> ../.moc/moc_applicationui.cpp:53: undefined reference to ApplicationUI::copyText(QByteArray)

I went through `applicationui.hpp` file and I saw the declaration of the copyText function as:

```
public:
  Q_INVOKABLE
    void copyText(QByteArray text);
```

I don't understand what's the error?

Answer (score 1):

You have `copyText` method declared in hpp but it is not implemented in cpp, just add this to your applicationui.cpp file :

```
ApplicationUI::copyText(QByteArray text) {
  // Your logic goes here
}
```